# вывод первой последовательности цифр, идущих в строке подряд

Tags: java, циклы, поиск

Дана строка, содержащая цифры. Нужно вывести первую последовательность цифр(если их больше одной), а остальные последовательности выводить не нужно.
Мой код находит цифры, но отсечь следующие последовательности не получается.

```
        char repeatChar = 0;
        int maxCount = 0;
        int currentMaxCount = 1;
        char[] digits = new char[string.length()];

        for (int i = 1; i < string.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i - 1)) && Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i))) {
                currentMaxCount++;
                if (currentMaxCount > maxCount) {
                    maxCount = currentMaxCount;
                    if (repeatChar != string.charAt(i - 1) && repeatChar != string.charAt(i)) {
                        digits[i - 1] = string.charAt(i - 1);
                        digits[i] = string.charAt(i);
                    }
                }
            } else if (currentMaxCount > 0) {
                currentMaxCount = 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits));
```

Comment: Каким образом пытаешься отсечь? Почему не получается? Какая ошибка?

Comment: Нужно вывести первую последовательность цифр в строке? Для строки `"a12b333cd456e"` ответом будет `"12"`? Не самую длинную последовательность цифр, не самую длинную последовательность повторяющейся цифры - просто первую? Поверхностный взгляд на переменные `currentMaxCount` и `repeatChar` наводит на мысли, что описанная задача не сходится с представленным кодом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам поможет оператор `break`, позволяющий досрочно закончить выполнение цикла.

```
for (int i = 1; i < string.length(); i++) {
  if (Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i - 1)) && Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i))) {
    currentMaxCount++;
    if (currentMaxCount > maxCount) {
      maxCount = currentMaxCount;
      if (repeatChar != string.charAt(i - 1) && repeatChar != string.charAt(i)) {
        digits[i - 1] = string.charAt(i - 1);
        digits[i] = string.charAt(i);
      }
    }
  } else if (currentMaxCount > 1) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Поскольку блок `else` срабатывает только тогда, когда последовательность закончилась или не найдена, то необходимо его изменить так, чтобы в этом месте проверялось, была ли найдена последовательность длиннее 1, что означает закончившеюся последовательност. В этом случае, цикл должен прерываться досрочно, чтобы не искать последовательности далее. Прерывание можно осуществить с помощью `break`.

Answer (score 2):

Можно решить задачу, используя расширенные стримы (например, с библиотекой [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)):

```java
String result = new String(
    IntStreamEx.of("a12b333cd456e".chars())
        .dropWhile(c -> !Character.isDigit(c))
        .takeWhile(Character::isDigit)
        .toByteArray()
);
```

PS: Начиная с Java 9 методы `dropWhile` и `takeWhile` уже есть у обычных стримов.

Comment: До этого мои познания ещё не дошли, говорят, эту задачу можно решить через регулярные выражения, но и здесь мои познания довольно скромны.

Comment: @Сергей ну да, можно написать просто `"a12b333cd456e".replaceAll(".*?(\\d+).*", "$1")` :)